# A multi-word verb which is the opposite of 'stress out'

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-requests

I ran a bunch of errands today that involved dealing with people who don't know what they are talking about, and when I got home there were six letters from the US government sitting in my mailbox, some contradicting information sent just four days earlier...

I felt overwhelmed, and a little ***stressed out.***

I wanted to say to my wife that I needed some time to ______________ before starting on the rest of my daily chores...

Is there a multi-word verb that would indicate ***de-stress out***?

I suppose that a single word might be 'decompress'...

My [research](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=opposite+of+stress+out)
was not fruitful...

Comment: 'Calm down' is often used in the UK, but I'd say is a ELL-level answer.

Comment: **take a breather** or **unwind**.

Comment: If you can accept a single word, then I'd suggest "relax."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can confirm "calm down" is also a common phrase in the US.

Comment: "Calm down" is common in the US but not super idiomatic in this scenario.  "Unwind" is probably the #1 candidate, but if you really need more than 1 word, "chill out," as suggested below, is your man.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could say 'I needed time to *chill out*'. According to [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chill-out):

> To **chill out** means to relax after you have done something tiring or stressful.

Comment: I should have thought of that...it seems that recently kids say "Take a chill pill'

Answer (score 2):

I suggest ***wind down***

> If you ***wind down***, you relax after doing something that has made you feel tired or tense.  ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wind-down))

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/wind_down.html) will give you some synonyms for the meaning

> to relax after a period of work or tension

(including the verb contained in your OP, ***de-stress***):

> ***loosen up, ease off, cool off***

I would personnally go for the one word verb, ***unwind*** in this situtation.